# Creating a grid using VTK Activiz C#

Tags: c#, vtk

I am trying to construct a structured grid (ie. mesh/cell) using `VTK` with Activiz *C#*. The very first example posted [here](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/CSharp/ActiViz.NET), shows how to create a cube. I have got this running fine.

Now I would like to extend this to a `grid/cell/mesh`, where I can specify the number of grid blocks in the x, y, and z directions, as well as the `gridblock` lengths, to produce a structured grid.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? This is a brief image of what I am trying to create:

[image]